# apply rate list with weight in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following set of data:

**Input:**

```
awbno       byhub      WEIGHT
 111          HO       2.50
 222          HO       3.00
 333          HO       2.40
 444          HO       0.80
 555          HO       1.00
```

**Rate List:**

- `<=` 1. kg = 2.5 rupees
- `>` 1 kg. / 0.500 gm. = 0.5 rupees

I am looking for the following ...

**Desired Output**

```
AWBNO     BYHUB     WEIGHT    AMOUNT
 111        HO      2.50      4.000
 222        HO      3.00      4.500
 333        HO      2.40      4.000
 444        HO      0.80      2.500
 555        HO      1.00      2.500
```

Comment: please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to include what have you tried and where are you stuck. SO isn't a code request comunity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbd328/1) in sqlfiddle:

```
select
    *,
    case when WEIGHT <= 1 then 2.5
         else 2.5 + CEILING((WEIGHT - 1) / 0.5) * 0.5 end as AMOUNT
from yourtable
```

Official doc [**ceiling**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceiling) says:

> Returns the smallest integer value not less than X

Answer (score 0):

For amount you can use `CASE` expression like

```
case when (weight - 1) <= 0 then 2.5 else 2.5 + ((weight - 1) / 0.500) * 0.5 end as amount
```

Comment: Rahul sir your query do not apply with 2.40kg

Answer (score 0):

```
Use below query to get your result :

CREATE TABLE #table ( awbno INT, byhub VARCHAR(100), WEIGHT DECIMAL(12,2) ,  
Amount DECIMAL(12,2))

INSERT INTO #table ( awbno , byhub, WEIGHT )
SELECT 111,'HO',2.50 UNION ALL
SELECT  222,'HO',3.00 UNION ALL
SELECT  333,'HO',2.40 UNION ALL
SELECT  444,'HO',0.80 UNION ALL
SELECT  555,'HO',1.00 

UPDATE #table SET Amount = CASE WHEN (WEIGHT-1)/0.5 < 1 THEN 2.5 WHEN WEIGHT  
> 1 THEN 2.5 + ( (WEIGHT-1)/0.5 * 0.5 ) END

SELECT * FROM #table
```